# Error in file with R

Tags: r

The aim is to use all the script that are in a folder (default) or the ones defined by the user in arguments.

If I type the default:

```
RScript.exe Detection.r --detection ALL
```

The result looks like (no problem):

```
[1] "script1"             "script2"
[3] "script3"
```

But if I manually define the scripts to use:

```
RScript.exe Detection.r --detection algo1,algo2
```

The result looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "algo1" "algo2"
```

And I have this error:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
argument 'description' incorrect
```

I don't know why it does not work.

By the way, the code where is handle this:

```
    if(opt$detectionMethods =='ALL') {
    detectionMethods <- list.files(paste(projectBasePath, '/modules/detections', sep=''))
    detectionMethods <- gsub("\\.r", "", detectionMethods)
} else {
    detectionMethods <- strsplit(opt$detectionMethods, ",")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `strsplit` does not return a parsed vector of items, but a list containing that parsed vector. This is because `strplit` can also deal with a list or vector as input (e.g. `c('file1,file2,file3', 'file4,file5,file6')`). In this case you do not need that functionality.

You can use `unlist` to cast the vector inside a list to only a vector. This makes the result identical to the output of `list.files`, which in turn should allow your code to work. For example:

```
unlist(strsplit('file1,file2,file3', split = ','))
[1] "file1" "file2" "file3"
```

You can also create a custom function:

```
simple_strsplit = function(...) {
    return(unlist(strsplit(...)))
}
```

which essentially passes on all its arguments `...` directly to `strplit`, but calls `unclass` before returning the result.

Comment: 'unlist' works like a charm in my situation, didn't know it was that simple. Thank you so much !